# Query regarding salary calculator advertisement title

Tags: support, advertising, salary-calculator

I saw the [advertisement](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/8799200754671041536) below in the Database Administrators Stack Exchange site about the Stack Overflow Salary Calculator.

In the title, the character `i` is looks like `l` or Capital `I`. In plain text

> DIscover your earnIng potentIal

The character `i` displayed in a different way. Is this purposely added like that or typo?

> [image: SO Ad]

Comment: Standard problem with images that are down-scaled from their original design.

Comment: I suspect this is more of a font problem than a scaling problem...